# Flatness of a scheme over a local ring versus over the residue field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The orthogonal group scheme associated to a quadratic form $q$ of rank $n$ defined over a domain $R$ is:
$$ \underline{\operatorname{O}}_q := \{ A \in \mathrm{GL}_{n,R} : q \circ A = q \}. $$
If $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $q(x,y)=x^2-5y^2$ then this reads:
\begin{align*} 
\underline{\operatorname{O}}_q &= 
        \left \{ 
         A=\begin{pmatrix}
            \alpha  & \beta  \\ 
            \gamma  & \delta \\ 
        \end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{GL}_{2,\mathbb{Z}} : 
       A^t 
     \begin{pmatrix}
            1  & 0  \\ 
            0  & -5 \\ 
        \end{pmatrix}
        A
        =\begin{pmatrix}
            1  & 0  \\ 
            0  & -5 \\ 
        \end{pmatrix}
        \right \}  \\ \nonumber
   &= \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta]/\left( \alpha^2-5\gamma^2-1, \alpha \beta -5\gamma \delta, 
    \beta^2-5\delta^2+5\right)
\end{align*}
whose coordinate ring is of Krull dimension $5-3=2$ as well as tensored with the localization $\underline{\operatorname{O}}_q \otimes \mathbb{Z}_5$.
Also its reduction at $(5)$ is $4-2=2$-dimensional:
\begin{align*} 
\overline{\operatorname{O}}_q := \underline{\operatorname{O}}_q \otimes \mathbb{F}_5 = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{F}_5[\alpha,\gamma,\delta,t]/\left(t\alpha\delta-1, \alpha^2-1\right). 
\end{align*}
Away of $(5)$ the reduction dimension is $4-3=1$.
But this does not imply that $\underline{\operatorname{O}}_q$ is not flat,
since equidimensionality is a necessary condition only when the rings are local and Prufer which is not the case in $\mathbb{Z}_5[\underline{\operatorname{O}}_q]$.

Comment: What do you mean by not flat over $\mathbf{F}_5$? Everything over a field is flat.

Comment: Do you really mean 'via' in your title, as opposed perhaps to 'versus'? Also, do you mean to distinguish $\mathbb Z_5$ from $\mathbb F_5$ in your post, where you use both? \\ Finally, TeX note: please use `\operatorname`, not `\mathrm`, for operators.  Compare $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb Z[\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, t]$ `\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb Z[\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, t]` to $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z[\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, t]$ `\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z[\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, t]`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Why is the coordinate ring of $\underline{O}_q$ over $\mathbf{Z}$ $1$-dimensional? The polynomial ring $\mathbf{Z}[\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta]$ is $5$-dimensional and you have 3 equations (the first one for the determinant is redundant, as the condition with the transpose implies that $\det A = \pm 1$ which is a unit in $\mathbf{Z}$), and so a naive dimension count gives $5-3 = 2$.

Comment: The condition with the transpose only implies that $5 \operatorname{det}(A)^2 = 5$, which is automatically satisfied modulo 5.

Comment: Yes, that's why the dimension jumps at $5$, since $\mathrm{det}(A)$ should not necessarily be $\pm 1$...